# Python regex how to find a substring that starts with a given word and ends with either of two words

Tags: python, regex, logging

I'm parsing a log file and trying to find a substring that starts with a given pattern (say `Start log` ) and ends with one of two patterns (say `exit code \d.` or `took \d* seconds.`), whichever is later.

I tried the following without success:

```py
block_regex1 = re.compile('Start log .*?(exit code \d.|took \d* seconds.)', re.DOTALL)
block_regex2 = re.compile('Start log .*? exit code \d.|Start log .*? took \d* seconds.)', re.DOTALL)

block_regex.findall(log)
```

Example log file:

```
Start log 1
doing stuff
Finished with exit code 1.
Start log 2
doing stuff
Finished with exit code 0.
log 2 took 12 seconds.
Start log 3
doing stuff
Finished with exit code 0.
log 3 took 10 seconds.
Start log 4
doing stuff
Finished with exit code 1.
```

With the above code it should output a list with:

- `Start log 1 doing stuff Finished with exit code 1.`
- `Start log 2 doing stuff Finished with exit code 0. log 2 took 12 seconds.`
- ...

Eventually I want to get the log ID, the exit code, and if present the time in seconds. I think I can get that using groups, still looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
Start log (?:(?!Start log).)*(?:exit code \d+|took \d* seconds)\.
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/5pN5fz/1). *In short*: matching as much text as possible from `Start log` until `exit code` or `took xxx second` without allowing `Start log` in between.

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Start log                'Start log '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Start log                'Start log'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    exit code                'exit code '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    took                     'took '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     seconds                 ' seconds'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
```

Comment: that works great, and awesome explanation, thank you! how would you recommend doing the second part of the task (getting job id, exit code and timing)?

Comment: @Pierre What about [this](https://tio.run/##TY5BasMwEEX3PsVHm0jEmDZdd9sLZBmV4ErjeKgzMtKEOpC7u0oIpav5PP6bmfmqY5K3deXznLIiU6NU9Fg0s5zwDrPXvvIpnbDzEtOdFr0Mg5cPFi4jRfywjqCFFSFFwkvn5dGHpvSN1x0KhSSxdKY59xpGKnVxpm5gif002bzxX/bPv1X3djedL1vr49ZtWvx7yjVzHWojB7UHu3SZ5qkPZA1Ma47Gtbg6DCljqQkseB79dG5dfwE)?

Comment: that looks great thanks! I had also found a way to do it directly using your regex, [like this](https://regex101.com/r/xGiqvM/1) -- with the assumption that if a time is given we know what the exit code is (#success!) Then we can extract each info using `finditer` and `group(n)`